# R: defining the axes of a ggplot box-plot of two features

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have this small dataset of yearly energy consumption in EJ (Exajoules) for coal and renewables:

```
   Year Coal_cons Renewable_cons
1  1965     58.10           0.21
2  1966     58.77           0.23
3  1967     57.82           0.24
4  1968     58.68           0.26
5  1969     60.48           0.27
6  1970     61.41           0.30
7  1971     61.08           0.32
8  1972     61.76           0.35
9  1973     63.60           0.37
10 1974     63.66           0.39
11 1975     64.89           0.39
12 1976     67.28           0.43
13 1977     69.27           0.47
14 1978     70.05           0.51
15 1979     73.31           0.56
16 1980     75.09           0.60
17 1981     76.14           0.63
18 1982     76.98           0.74
19 1983     79.36           0.84
20 1984     82.80           0.96
21 1985     86.35           1.01
22 1986     87.32           1.15
23 1987     90.76           1.21
24 1988     93.47           1.26
25 1989     94.37           1.40
26 1990     93.22           1.58
27 1991     92.31           1.66
28 1992     91.98           1.75
29 1993     92.43           1.82
30 1994     92.78           1.91
31 1995     93.44           2.01
32 1996     95.66           2.04
33 1997     95.50           2.20
34 1998     94.89           2.31
35 1999     95.48           2.46
36 2000     98.70           2.64
37 2001    100.27           2.75
38 2002    104.20           3.10
39 2003    113.39           3.37
40 2004    121.19           3.87
41 2005    130.21           4.37
42 2006    137.05           5.03
43 2007    144.80           5.94
44 2008    146.77           7.16
45 2009    144.53           8.24
46 2010    151.19           9.70
47 2011    158.46          11.12
48 2012    159.07          12.60
49 2013    161.98          14.36
50 2014    161.84          16.03
51 2015    157.84          18.08
52 2016    155.50          20.06
53 2017    156.09          23.04
54 2018    158.79          25.83
55 2019    157.86          28.98
```

I would like to implement the code below so I achieve a similar output to the picture:
[image]

However, it is not clear to me how I can define the axis as they are in individual columns.

How could I set up my axes to achieve a similar output as the one on the picture?

Comment: So instead of `Obama` and `Trump` you want to show `Coal` and `Renewables` ?

Comment: @markus Yes! I'm just having a hard time knowing how to define the axes or even if this is the best plot to use considering I have yearly data... What are your suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(2:3) %>%   # pivot_longer to one column for names and one for values
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value, color = name)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_point(position = position_jitter(width = 0.3)) # position_jitter for the dots
```

[image]

Here is an alternative method using facets so the second boxplot is easier to read. You lose the ability to directly compare the y scales.

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(2:3) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value, color = name)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_point(position = position_jitter(width = 0.3)) + 
  facet_wrap(~name, scales = "free")
```

[image]

Here is a `dput()` of the data.

```
structure(list(Year = c(1965, 1966, 1967, 1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 
                        1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 
                        1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 
                        1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 
                        2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 
                        2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 
                        2019), 
               Coal_cons = c(58.1, 58.77, 57.82, 58.68, 60.48, 61.41, 61.08, 
                             61.76, 63.6, 63.66, 64.89, 67.28, 69.27, 70.05, 
                             73.31, 75.09, 76.14, 76.98, 79.36, 82.8, 86.35, 
                             87.32, 90.76, 93.47, 94.37, 93.22, 92.31, 91.98, 
                             92.43, 92.78, 93.44, 95.66, 95.5, 94.89, 95.48, 
                             98.7, 100.27, 104.2, 113.39, 121.19, 130.21, 
                             137.05, 144.8, 146.77, 144.53, 151.19, 158.46, 
                             159.07, 161.98, 161.84, 157.84, 155.5, 156.09, 
                             158.79, 157.86), 
               Renewable_cons = c(0.21, 0.23, 0.24, 0.26, 0.27, 0.3, 0.32, 
                                  0.35, 0.37, 0.39, 0.39, 0.43, 0.47, 0.51, 
                                  0.56, 0.6, 0.63, 0.74, 0.84, 0.96, 1.01, 
                                  1.15, 1.21, 1.26, 1.4, 1.58, 1.66, 1.75, 
                                  1.82, 1.91, 2.01, 2.04, 2.2, 2.31, 2.46, 
                                  2.64, 2.75, 3.1, 3.37, 3.87, 4.37, 5.03, 
                                  5.94, 7.16, 8.24, 9.7, 11.12, 12.6, 14.36, 
                                  16.03, 18.08, 20.06, 23.04, 25.83, 28.98)), 
          class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
          row.names = c(NA, -55L))
```

Comment: I got this error: Error in UseMethod("pivot_longer") : 
  no applicable method for 'pivot_longer' applied to an object of class "function"

Comment: @Joehat That might be caused by the `df`, which is also a function. Rename your data to `df1` and try again.

Comment: Maybe this is not the best plot to use to compare this data. What would you suggest to me to do?

Comment: This is a fine plot to use depending on what you want to communicate. Do you want to communicate that `coal_cons` tends to be larger and have a larger range than `renewable_cons`? This is a fine plot for that purpose. I added an alternate plot that separates them into panels with independent y axes. You can read the `renewable_cons` boxplot more easily, but it is harder to compare the two categories.